# Dialog not showing up above a frame

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

In my WPF application, i have a frame that i use to open some links from the internet and i have button and inside it i have a dialog(Mahapp control) that i use to close the application.So when i open a url in the frame and i need to close the application, the dialog is not displayed above the frame.

```
    private async void ShowModalDialog_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    popup.IsEnabled = false;
     this.MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme = UseAccentForDialog.IsEnabled ? MetroDialogColorScheme.Accented : MetroDialogColorScheme.Theme;
     var result = await this.ShowInputAsync("FERMETURE DE L'APPLICATION.", "Tu dois demander à tes parents pour quitter." + "\n" + "Indiquer votre mot de passe pour quitter l'application.");
     var wcf = new ServiceReferenceParent.ParentServiceClient();
     Parent par = wcf.GetParent(parent.ParentId);
    if (result == par.Password) //user pressed cancel
        Application.Current.Shutdown() ;
}
```

Comment: What i understood is you want conformation before closing the application. right?

Comment: yes that's what i mean